# ic_launcher_foreground.xml is having trouble finding several attributes while gradle build

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

i just upgraded from android studio 2.1 to a stable 3.0 and i'm getting errors while making a new project on it (i am also new to android studio :D)
here are the errors am getting

1. Error:(7) No resource identifier found for attribute 'fillType' in package 'android'
2. Error:(28) No resource identifier found for attribute 'fillType' in package 'android'
3. Error:(13) No resource identifier found for attribute 'endX' in package 'android'
4. Error:(13) No resource identifier found for attribute 'startX' in package 'android'
5. Error:(19) No resource identifier found for attribute 'offset' in package 'android'

and a couple of exceptions

1. Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process E:\AndroidSDK\build-tools\27.0.1\aapt.exe with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I E:\AndroidSDK\platforms\android-23\android.jar -M \?\C:\Users\ShaD iLiX\AndroidStudioProjects\Test1\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\ShaD iLiX\AndroidStudioProjects\Test1\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug -m -J \?\C:\Users\ShaD iLiX\AndroidStudioProjects\Test1\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\ShaD iLiX\AndroidStudioProjects\Test1\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\resources-debug.ap_ --custom-package com.example.shadilix.test1 -0 apk --output-text-symbols \?\C:\Users\ShaD iLiX\AndroidStudioProjects\Test1\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug --no-version-vectors}
2. Error:com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process E:\AndroidSDK\build-tools\27.0.1\aapt.exe with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I E:\AndroidSDK\platforms\android-23\android.jar -M \?\C:\Users\ShaD iLiX\AndroidStudioProjects\Test1\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\ShaD iLiX\AndroidStudioProjects\Test1\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug -m -J \?\C:\Users\ShaD iLiX\AndroidStudioProjects\Test1\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\ShaD iLiX\AndroidStudioProjects\Test1\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\resources-debug.ap_ --custom-package com.example.shadilix.test1 -0 apk --output-text-symbols \?\C:\Users\ShaD iLiX\AndroidStudioProjects\Test1\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug --no-version-vectors}
3. Error:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'E:\AndroidSDK\build-tools\27.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

   4. Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

      > Failed to execute aapt

Here is the ic_Launcher_foreground.xml code :

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
android:width="108dp"
android:height="108dp"
android:viewportHeight="108"
android:viewportWidth="108">
<path
    android:fillType="evenOdd"
    android:pathData="M32,64C32,64 38.39,52.99 44.13,50.95C51.37,48.37 70.14,49.57 70.14,49.57L108.26,87.69L108,109.01L75.97,107.97L32,64Z"
    android:strokeColor="#00000000"
    android:strokeWidth="1">
    <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
        <gradient
            android:endX="78.5885"
            android:endY="90.9159"
            android:startX="48.7653"
            android:startY="61.0927"
            android:type="linear">
            <item
                android:color="#44000000"
                android:offset="0.0" />
            <item
                android:color="#00000000"
                android:offset="1.0" />
        </gradient>
    </aapt:attr>
</path>
<path
    android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:fillType="nonZero"
    android:pathData="M66.94,46.02L66.94,46.02C72.44,50.07 76,56.61 76,64L32,64C32,56.61 35.56,50.11 40.98,46.06L36.18,41.19C35.45,40.45 35.45,39.3 36.18,38.56C36.91,37.81 38.05,37.81 38.78,38.56L44.25,44.05C47.18,42.57 50.48,41.71 54,41.71C57.48,41.71 60.78,42.57 63.68,44.05L69.11,38.56C69.84,37.81 70.98,37.81 71.71,38.56C72.44,39.3 72.44,40.45 71.71,41.19L66.94,46.02ZM62.94,56.92C64.08,56.92 65,56.01 65,54.88C65,53.76 64.08,52.85 62.94,52.85C61.8,52.85 60.88,53.76 60.88,54.88C60.88,56.01 61.8,56.92 62.94,56.92ZM45.06,56.92C46.2,56.92 47.13,56.01 47.13,54.88C47.13,53.76 46.2,52.85 45.06,52.85C43.92,52.85 43,53.76 43,54.88C43,56.01 43.92,56.92 45.06,56.92Z"
    android:strokeColor="#00000000"
    android:strokeWidth="1" />
```

here is My build.gradle file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.shadilix.test1"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Did you get any solution for this error ? I am facing same error.

Answer (score 0):

clean build and/or restart and invalidate might solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem yesterday while making a copy of original project.
The solution that I found was to make a zip file of the original project at separate location and then open/build it.

The above problem arises because it cannot find the required files for ic_launcher_background,just my guess.